# Why should I update jQuery from 1.9.1 to 2.0.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, upgrade

I have a Chrome-specific web app that uses jQuery to help handle the styling. There's nothing very advanced in there; it's all things that could've been done with standard JavaScript (basically adding/removing classes on the fly, changing position values etc.), it's just easier to type and read using jQuery. Is there any actual point in upgrading from 1.9.1 to 2.0.2 (and each subsequent version) and going through the effort of testing everything when it is stable and works beautifully in 1.9.1?

*Edit: I should add that no jQuery plug-ins are being used either.*

Comment: Have you tried reading the changelog documentation? Perhaps a feature/bug was added/fixed that you care about.

Comment: If it were my project I would upgrade the jQuery version next time I needed to make other changes to the code that would require retesting anyway, otherwise I'd leave it alone.

Comment: The major change is browser compatibility. jQuery 2.0+ drops support for IE8, finally.

Comment: @elclanrs ...which is actually somewhat useful for a Chrome-only app.

Comment: I would only update it if i had to edit it, and then i'd go to 2.x if it's only for chrome.

Comment: @MattBall: Exactly, that's my point. The update should be fine although probably unnecessary.

Comment: The web app is something in progress - so you're saying that if I continue developing it (which I currently am) then I should update it, otherwise leave it as is?

Comment: Well it's a matter of changing _one_ line in your script and see if everything still works, if it does then keep new version. If it doesn't, try and fix it, if you can't, keep old version. This is not worthy of a question TBH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You could try reading through the changelogs and see if there are any known issues related to your code that are fixed in newer versions. If the app is working fine, then leave it :)